# Domain admin can't log into Report Server (Could not load folder contents)

Tags: reporting-services, permissions

I'm getting this error when trying to browse to `http://localhost/reports/browse/`:

[image: SSRS Permissions Error]

I'm running as Domain Admin under full permissions:

[image]

I can only get to these settings by running Chrome as administrator.

I also have granted myself full permissions on the Home Folder:

[image]

This is a clean install of SSRS 2016-CU8.

How can I configure this so I don't have to run the browser as administrator?

**--EDIT--**

To clarify, the domain admin account is in the Builtin\Administrators group. I also tried explicitly adding the domain admin to the SSRS permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Builtin\Administrators is not the same as your domain admin account.  I would either add the account explicitly or as part of a AD group.  Your domain admin would be somethings like domain\adminaccoutname here.

Jesse

Comment: Pardon me, I should have clarified... the domain admin is in the Builtin\Administrators group. I also already tried adding the account specifically to the SSRS permissions. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think SSRS authentication process is going to recognize local server groups, just AD.  Adding the domain account to both overall site security and folder security should work.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the failed trust relationship for the domain; this machine has been offsite for well over thirty days. I didn't mention this earlier as I didn't suspect it as the cause, but I'm starting to head in that direction. FYI I'll be configuring a VPN next week, at which time I'll repair the relationship and try again.